# Using tv remote to control volume through HDMI CEC

Tags: cec-client

Is this possible?

- I have my Raspberry Pi connected to my Philips smart tv via HDMI.
- I've made sure that the CEC protocol is sending and receiving messages using `cec-client`
- Various actions on the remote control results in messages in the CEC debug stream

  - Pressing the volume up/down buttons does not register in the CEC debug stream
- Setting "Audio Out" on the TV to "HDMI Sound System" results in an onscreen message claiming that no sound system is connected and that the TV will use it's internal speakers until one is connected.

I tried reporting my device as an Audio System:

```
tx 50:84:10:00:05
TRAFFIC: [        13723743] << 50:84:10:00:05
WARNING: [        13723926] unhandled response received: opcode=84 initiator=1 destination=0 response=0
DEBUG:   [        13724747] command 'report physical address' timeout
```

This has no effect on what is described above.

**How can I make my TV see my Raspberry Pi as an "HDMI Sound System"?**

**How can I intercept volume signals from my TV's remote control (via HDMI)?**

Answer (score 2):

`cec-client -t a` did the trick.

Now I'm receiving signals whenever I press the volume buttons on the remote control